# XSLT - How to read all child nodes in order, having same and different name tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the below XML file that i want to parse to create HTML. My problem is that i am not able to parse it as I would like.

What i want to do is output my `<items>` as html. So i want a `<paragraph>` to be a `<div>`, `<image>`to be an  `<img>` and its child nodes to be its properties 'src' and 'alt'.

```
<itemlist>
    <item>
        <paragraph>pA</paragraph>
        <image>
            <url>http://www.com/image.jpg</url>
            <title>default image</title>
        </image>
        <paragraph>pB</paragraph>
        <paragraph>pC</paragraph>
        <link target='#'>linkA</link>
        <paragraph>pD</paragraph>
        <link target='#' >linkB</link>
        <image>
            <url>http://www.com/image2.jpg</url>
            <title>default image 2</title>
        </image>
        </item>
        <item>      
        <paragraph>pB</paragraph>
        <paragraph>pC</paragraph>
        <image>
            <url>http://www.com/image2.jpg</url>
            <title>default image 2</title>
        </image>
        <link target='#'>linkA</link>
        <paragraph>pD</paragraph>
        <link target='#'>linkB</link>
        </item>
    </itemlist>
```

If I do a foreach loop on  `<item>` and write values by applying the templates, such as match='paragraph' followed by match='image', then all `<paragraph>` will be written before the `<image>`, which will not result in correct output.

Below is the output that i am expecting. Anyone has an idea how to do it?

```
<div id="item">
    <div>pA</div>
    <img src='http://www.com/image.jpg' title='default image' />
    <div>pB</div>
    <div>pC</div>
    <a href='#'>linkA</a>
    <div>pD</div>
    <img src='http://www.com/image2.jpg' title='default image 2' />
</div>
<div id="item">
    <div>pB</div>
    <div>pC</div>
    <img src='http://www.com/image2.jpg' title='default image 2' />
    <a href='#'>linkA</a>
    <div>pD</div>
    <a href='#'>linkB</a>
</div>
```

-----edit----
Currently I have something like this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="itemlist/item">
<xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="link"/>


  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="link">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ? :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="//paragraph">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//image">
        <img>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </img>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: while your answer does output the result i showed. Its does not seem to be correct for me. I have added the code I'm working with

Comment: @Daniel This solution works, the error must be on your side. See http://www.xmlplayground.com/SaB3U9.

Comment: Stefanos, one side note: `match` expressions do not require full XPath expressions. `<xsl:template match="image">` etc. is enough.

Comment: Yeah i knew it worked, i just didn't realize how to adapt it to what i required. Thanks. Would not have done it without you.